# How to export each xlsx page to csv from bash?

Tags: bash, export-to-csv, xlsx

There are many examples on how to export an excel file to csv, but all forms only export the **first page**. I use Linux and I would like to know if there is some way via bash to export all the pages to different csv files, for example:

```sh
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv file.xlsx
```

But it only exports the first page.

Comment: Apparently there's a tool called [`xlsx2csv`](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv) that can do it, using its `-s` option.

Comment: It is part of the `catdoc` package.

Comment: Some folks just install it in their home directory via `pip`  fwiw.